# Get an object in a Many-to-Many Relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-queryset

I have these two models:

```
class Instrument(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

class Instrumentation(models.Model):
    instrument = models.ManyToManyField(Instrument, verbose_name=_('instrument'), related_name='instrumentation', blank=True)
```

I want to add a save method to the Instrument model where the method will check if Instrumentation already has an object that has a single relationship with the current instrument. If not, I will create an instrumentation object with one relationship to the current instrument. If so, then nothing happens. If instrumentation has another object that has relationships to violin, violin and cello. It will ignore that.

For example.

I am trying to save an instrument object called 'violin'. the instrument save method will search instrumentation table to see if there is an instrumentation object that contain a single relationship with violin. If it doesn't exist, then it will create the instrumentation object with a relationship with 'violin'.

I have something like but I can't get the filter right:

In the instrument model:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try: 
        exists = Instrumentation.objects.filter(name=self.name)
    except:
        new = Instrumentation.objects.create(
            instrument=self.pk,
            name=self.name,)
        new.save()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The problem is that before you save such `Instrumentation` at the database, then you can not construct a many-to-many relation to an `Instrument`, since at the moment it has no primary key to refer to.

Comment: Based on your model, an `Instrumentation` has no `name` field by the way.

Comment: The Instrument already exists. Just trying to create the instrumentation object.

Comment: Basically want I am trying to do is single instrument piece of music have single instrumentations.  When I create a new instrument, I want to go back in and press save to create the instrumentation object. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: but you override the `save(..)` method of the `Instrument` object. So if `self.pk` is `None`, then it means there is no record yet.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned in comments and in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships), you can't add records via M2M relations before your target record is saved (get's the PR assigned). If you actually need to create `Instrumentation` objects that have same name as `Instrument` and add this object to `Instrument`, if it's still doesn't exists, then you can go this way:

I assume that you anyway want to save an `Instument` record no metter if `Instrumentation` exists or not:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    if not Instrumentation.objects.filter(name=self.name).exists()
        instrumentation = Instrumentation.objects.create(name=self.name)
        self.instrumentation.add(instrumentation)
```